# How to fix Post View on LinkedIn?

Tags: next.js, metadata, linkedin-api, share-open-graph

I've an issue with LinkedIn OpenGraph metadata. As image it takes first image in body not og:image... On Facebook it works correctly but not on LinkedIn.

```
title: post.title,
description: post.description,
openGraph: {
  title: post.title,
  description: post.description,
  url: `https://www.infele.pl/blog/post/${post.slug.current}`,
  siteName: "infele.pl",
  images: [
    {
      url: urlFor(post.mainImage).url(),
    },
  ],
  locale: "pl_PL",
  type: "article",
  authors: post.author.name,
  publishedTime: new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleDateString("pl-PL", {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric",
  }),
},
robots: {
  index: true,
  follow: true,
  googleBot: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
  },
},
twitter: {
  card: "summary_large_image",
  title: post.title,
  description: post.description,
  images: [urlFor(post.mainImage).url()],
},
verification: {
  google: "",
},
alternates: {
  canonical: `https://www.infele.pl/blog/post/${post.slug.current}`,
},
```

};

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.infele.pl%2Fblog%2Fpost%2Fniesamowite-doswiadczenie-next-js-tailwind-css-i-sanity-cms

Could you help me?